# Date and Time picker for Acumatica PXGridColumn

Tags: acumatica

I have a DateTime value displayed in a PXGrid but when I edit it, it only allows my to select a date and giving me a time of 12:00 AM. How can I implement a data and time control?

View mode

[image]

Edit mode

[image]

```
<px:PXGrid ID="myGrid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Style="z-index: 100" 
        Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Details">
        <Levels>
            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="LineItemsView">
                <RowTemplate>
                    <px:PXDateTimeEdit ID="rtReceivedDate" TimeMode="true" runat="server" DataField="ReceivedDate" />
                </RowTemplate>
                   <Columns>
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Itemname" Width="150" />
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Itemdesc" Width="200" />
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Qty" Width="100" />
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Price" Width="150" />
                        <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ReceivedDate" Width="150" />
                        
                    </Columns>
                </px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
        <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
    </px:PXGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must utilize the `[PXDBDateAndTime(PreserveTime = true)]` attribute on your DateTime DAC field as well as the `DisplayFormat` property of the `PXGridColumn`.

DAC Example :

```
public sealed class APTranExtension : PXCacheExtension<APTran>
{
    public abstract class usrDateTime : BqlDateTime.Field<usrDateTime>
    {
    }
    [PXDBDateAndTime(PreserveTime = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Date Time")]
    public DateTime? UsrDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

ASPX :

```
                            <Columns>
                                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="UsrDateTime" DisplayFormat="g"/>
                            <Columns>
```

Result :

[image: PXDBDateAndTime]

Comment: I have the date displaying, however when I click on the field to edit, the time disappears and am unable to change the time.

Comment: Either other code you have is interfering or you have not implemented as I have. Do you have a row template item defined as in your ? If so remove it.