# PXDBTimeAttribute How to change minute steps in selector

Tags: acumatica

version 21 R2

I have a DateTime field that is adorned with the PXDBTime attribute in order to allow the user to select a time during the day.  I have the attribute set up like this:

```
[PXDBTime(DisplayMask = "t", UseTimeZone = false)]
```

This results is a selector for the field on the screen that has time values for every thirty minutes - 12:00 AM, 12:30 AM, 1:00 AM, etc.

How can I change that 30-minute step to something else?  Is it possible?  Where is the 30 minutes coming from in Acumatica?

So, if I set it to 60 minutes, I would have a dropdown that has 12:00 AM, 1:00 AM, 2:00 AM, etc. as available values.

Thanks for any recommendations.

Comment: If you want to select a specific time the following answer would allow such https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75617257/date-and-time-picker-for-acumatica-pxgridcolumn/75620630#75620630

Comment: He was hoping to have a dropdown that has a choice of time options I think. That answer is just for a time text field edit?

Comment: Yes, the way that I have it now (with the "t" DisplayMask) only shows the time part of the date time, which is what is needed.  I just need to the dropdown options to be in other increments than 30 minutes.  The default seems to be 30 minutes.  Not sure if there's a way to change that?